# Change the footer pagenumber (Decimal) into the title abbreviation

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, footer, xsl-fo, dita

I'm doing the dita-ot pdf conversion, using lot of topic dita template and requirement is to changing the decimal page numbers into the topic title abbreviation for one topic alone, other topic it should be in decimal page number only

In the commons.xsl

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]">

<xsl:when test="not(ancestor::*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]) and not(ancestor::ot-placeholder:glossarylist)">
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="{$page-sequence-reference}" xsl:use-attribute-sets="__force__page__count" initial-page-number="1">
<xsl:call-template name="startPageNumbering"/>
</fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:when>

</xsl:template>
```

Commons-attr.xsl:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="__force__page__count">
    <xsl:attribute name="force-page-count">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name(/*) = 'bookmap'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'even'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'auto'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

There is no templates for `startPageNumbering`, as per the `initial-page-number` and `force_page_count`, decimal page number getting reset for every topic as starting with page number 1. So that I just want to change the one topic decimal page number into the corresponding topic title abbreviation

for eg:

```
<topic class="- topic/topic ">
<title class="- topic/title " outputclass="CD_Section_Heading">DEFINITIONS</title>
</topic>
```

for this `DEFINITIONS` title topic footer page number should be `DEF` as like that I have few topics that should get title abbreviation as Footer instead of decimal page number. Please help me and let me know if you need any more. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Are you generating `fo:page-sequence` per topic? The footer belongs `fo:static-content`. Have you consider to adopt `fo:marker` (in main FO) and `fo:retrieve-marker` (in `fo:static-content`) combination?

Comment: @tmakita is correct. The page number is generated by an `fo:page-number` in an `fo:static-content`. Which `fo:static-content` is used is determined by the current `fo:simple-page-master`. You probably need a separate `fo:simple-page-master` for your 'DEFINITIONS' pages that uses an `fo:region-after` with a different `region-name` that corresponds to an `fo:static-content` that you also create that generates 'DEF' instead of containing an `fo:page-number`. I don't know enough about the DITA-OT to tell you how to fit all that into the DITA-OT processing.

Comment: @TonyGraham Thanks for your suggestion, as per the suggestion its working well, but having some other issue on handle this. Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68116704/need-to-change-the-footer-value-as-per-the-parent-and-child-topic

Comment: @tmakita Thanks for your suggestion, as per the suggestion its working well, but having some other issue on handle this. Please take a look on this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68116704/need-to-change-the-footer-value-as-per-the-parent-and-child-topic