# Need to change the footer value as per the parent and child topic

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, dita, dita-ot

Now I'm working on creating the footer value for pdf using DITA-OT. I'm having multiple child topics with outputclass attribute

Dita Input:

```
<topic outputclass="h1">
   <title outputclass="CD_Map_Heading-hide">HIDE TOPIC</title>
   <topic outputclass="h2">
      <title>DEFINITION</title>
   </topic>
   <topic outputclass="h3">
      <title>REVOLUTION</title>
   </topic>
</topic>
```

Static Content XSL:

```
<xsl:template name="insertBodyOddFooter">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="odd-body-footer">
        <fo:block>&#160;</fo:block>
        <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="__body__odd__footer">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="*[contains(@outputclass, 'h2')]">
                       <xsl:text>DEF</xsl:text>
                 </xsl:when>
                 <xsl:when test="*[contains(@outputclass, 'h3')]">
                        <xsl:text>REV</xsl:text>
                 </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <fo:block-container position="absolute">
                        <fo:block padding-top="20pt"  text-align="center">
                            <fo:page-number/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:block-container>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm getting only `DEF` as footnote for this all the topic. But I need every topic pages should their own footer value, that means for the `h3` output class topic should get `REF` as footer. but I'm getting `DEF`. So please help me to get the footer value for that corresponding topic pages. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Input: XML -> Transformation: XSLT -> Output: XML (XSL-FO) - so if you want help with your modifications to your XSLT, you need to provide a proper input XML, your current, complete XSLT, and the XML output you want.

Comment: @AlexanderGräf I have edited, Please see and help me on this

Comment: The XSLT isn't anywhere near complete. Not only does it lack a xsl:stylesheet tag, but there is nothing in the input that the single template you provided could match, as it is a named template.